# Code Review questions must contain code

Tags: discussion, questions, code-length

[As requested by Kaz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/what-would-clippy-say/6689#6689) and approved by the voters here on meta, questions asked on Code Review that do not contain code are now blocked.

I've configured this initially as a three-line minimum (or three separate bits of code-formatted text, or any combination of the two). This may be too much; it may more easily be too little. Happy to change it to anything else y'all decide is right.

If insufficient code is included in the question, a small error is shown below the editor:

> [image: Questions on Code Review Stack Exchange must contain at least 3 lines of code. For details, see the Help Center]

This links to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, which seems like a fairly comprehensive set of instructions on the matter.

As with the code formatting check and [the code/explanation ratio check](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8366/what-to-do-about-its-asking-for-more-details/8371#8371), this only applies to users at or below 200 reputation.

Please let me know if you have any questions or encounter any problems with this.

Comment: Thanks for this feature. It will reduce a lot of noise from our site.

Comment: Does this still [allow posts involving graphic languages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47323480#47323480)? e.g. [scratch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scratch) - also [related post about scratch questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5923/120114)

Comment: Would've blocked precisely one of the three scratch questions here, @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ. Logic merely counts `<code></code>` and newlines within.

Comment: any idea how [this particular question made it through the filter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/209554/37660)?

Comment: Apparently the API bypasses validation, @Vogel612 (mobile app). I'll look into it.

Comment: [Does moderators bypass this?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/209570/31562)

Comment: If they have over 200 rep, yeah @SimonForsberg

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. Forgot about that. That's what happens when you miss the sign that says "Kids, don't try this at home".

Comment: Think I figured it out, @Vogel612 - the API isn't bypassing this check, this check doesn't even exist in the codebase that the API is running! Should work properly after the next API build. And... yeah, I spent way too much time chasing my tail before that occurred to me.

Comment: this is awesome, thank you for hearing us and making this happen

Comment: LOL _As requested by Kaz_ - this was like two years ago _answered Mar 30 '16 at 8:06_ :-\

Comment: Yeah... We had no suitable functionality in our system for quickly achieving such a goal, @t3chb0t - so it got tossed around to various people on various lists for a while. Finally I just sat down and wrote a new check for the purpose; sorry for the delay, but... Better late than never.